# if else changing a text field

Tags: javascript

I have this code and it is not working It is just for testing.

HTML

```
<a id="sp">test</a></li>
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('sp').innerHTML = 'test1';

var a == 'undefined'
IF (a == "undefined"){
    document.getElementById('sp').innerHTML = 'inline';
}ELSE{
     document.getElementById('sp').innerHTML = 'inline1';
}
```

The code is not entering the `if`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: that fiddle has nothing to do with the above code.

Comment: don't write 'IF' and 'ELSE' in caps, maybe?

Comment: if you clear the if it changes the value

Comment: var a == 'undefined' are you sure about that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the assigning you change to

`var a = "undefined"` and not `==`

Comment: Tanks to all and sorry for this error. The problem was the IF and the in lower case and what @kalyan said

Answer (score 3):

The quoted code has at *least* three significant, basic syntax errors. It's not just not entering the `if`, it's not doing anything at all. Look in your JavaScript console for the error messages, trust me they're there.

```
document.getElementById('sp').innerHTML = 'test1';

// 1. You want =, not ==, below. And a semicolon would be good.
var a == 'undefined'

// 2. IF should be in all lower case (if)
IF (a == "undefined"){
  document.getElementById('sp').innerHTML = 'inline';
// 3. ELSE should be in all lower case (else)
}ELSE{
   document.getElementById('sp').innerHTML = 'inline1';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the string 'undefined' is not the same as being actually undefined.

`if` and `else` are lower case.

```
document.getElementById('sp').innerHTML = 'test1';

var a = 'undefined';
if (a === 'undefined') {
  document.getElementById('sp').innerHTML = 'inline';
} else {
  document.getElementById('sp').innerHTML = 'inline1';
}
```

If you are actually trying to work out if a is properly undefined, use...

```
if (typeof a === 'undefined') {
  document.getElementById('sp').innerHTML = 'inline';
} else {
  document.getElementById('sp').innerHTML = 'inline1';
}
```

Comment: Still has a basic syntax error preventing it from compiling (look closely at that `var` statement, or at my answer).

Comment: Thanks for the spot! Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing your code in head section, move it to body tag..
secondly, remove one "=" from var a=='undefined'.

here is the working code example

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
<a id="sp">test</a>
<script language="javascript">
document.getElementById('sp').innerHTML = 'test1'; 
var a = 'undefined' 

if (a == "undefined")
{
  document.getElementById('sp').innerHTML = 'inline';
}
else
{
   document.getElementById('sp').innerHTML = 'inline1';
}

</script>
</body>
```